# C++ - Expected function body after function declarator - Xcode 9.0

Tags: c++, xcode9

I'm getting quite confused by the error detailed below:

```
#include "width.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::string;      using std::vector;
using std::max;
//Expected function body after function declarator error message here
string::size_type width(const vector<string>& v)
{
    string::size_type maxlen = 0;
    for (vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i)
    {
        maxlen = max(maxlen, v[i].size());
    }
    return maxlen;
}
```

with the header file being as follows:

```
#ifndef GUARD_width_hpp
#define GUARD_width_hpp

#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::string::size_type width(const std::vector<std::string>&)

#endif /* width_hpp */
```

Could someone provide me with some assistance?

Cheers!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include *all* relevant code (and *only* relevant code) in it as *text*. In your case, this means the contents of `width.hpp` too.

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved: I added a semi-colon after the function declarator in the header file. Thanks Gang!